# Select drop-down value by text array where %like% jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use jQuery if title input into my control panel have %like% some words

like

```
I love to eat apple
```

and I need to find love, apple

if found let jQuery select from dropdown menu value id 5

```
$("#HowYouKnow option").each(function() {
  if($(this).text() == theText) {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
  }                        
});
```

I found this code that when found text = text 
I need it %like% text with array to use many text ('text1','text2')

Comment: You can use single regex `$(this).text().match(/^(love|apple)$/)`

Comment: good , i need to select dropdown menu value 5 when it found

Comment: Use `$("#HowYouKnow").val(5);`

Comment: thanks , but it's will set 5 , i need to select dropdown menu

Comment: it will select dropdown item https://jsfiddle.net/9ppqpuqt/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9ppqpuqt/6/

Comment: `/^(love|apple)$/` will match full love or full apple if you want to match love or apple inside text use `/love|apple/`

Comment: If you want to get value of input don't use `text()` but `val()` https://jsfiddle.net/9ppqpuqt/7/

Comment: thanks it's work https://jsfiddle.net/9ppqpuqt/8/ , please set answer to select  you right answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select dropdown item based on input use this code:

```
if($("#input").val().match(/love|apple/)) {
    $("#select").val(5);
}
```